# How can I edit only the last record in a p:dataTable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In each query, records are variables and only need to edit the last record, the cell Total-Student.

```
<p:panel style="width:40%; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 20px;"> 
    <h:form>    
        <p:dataTable id="aviableCuotas" var="pag" value="#{loginController.pagos}">
            <p:column  headerText="Year" styleClass="tableHeader">  
                <h:outputText  value="#{pag.year}" styleClass="tableContent"/>  
            </p:column>  

            <p:column  headerText="Total Students" styleClass="tableHeader">  
                <h:outputText value="#{pag.estadistic}" styleClass="tableContent" /> 
            </p:column> 
         </p:dataTable> 
    </h:form>

    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="Calculate" action="#{loginBean.getLogin}" style="float: right" />
    </h:form>
</p:panel>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If it is a total of something (number of students) then, why do you need to edit the total? It should be calculated automatically.

Comment: It is not total of number of students, the last row is also a statistic, total student is only column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want edit just one column use this:

```
 <p:dataTable id="aviableCuotas" var="pag" value="#{loginController.pagos}" editable="true" editMode="cell">
<p:column  headerText="Year" styleClass="tableHeader">  
    <h:outputText  value="#{pag.year}" styleClass="tableContent"/>  
</p:column>  

<p:column  headerText="Total Students" styleClass="tableHeader">        
    <p:cellEditor>  
       <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{pag.estadistic}" styleClass="tableContent" /> </f:facet>  
       <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{pag.estadistic}" styleClass="tableContent"/></f:facet>  
    </p:cellEditor>  
</p:column> 
</p:dataTable>
```

And if you want only modify last row use that:

```
<p:dataTable id="aviableCuotas" var="pag" value="#{loginController.pagos}" editable="true" editMode="cell" rowIndexVar="i">
<p:column  headerText="Year" styleClass="tableHeader">  
    <h:outputText  value="#{pag.year}" styleClass="tableContent"/>  
</p:column>  

<p:column  headerText="Total Students" styleClass="tableHeader">        
    <p:cellEditor rendered="#{i == (loginController.pagos.size() - 1)}">  
       <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{pag.estadistic}" styleClass="tableContent" /> </f:facet>  
       <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{pag.estadistic}" styleClass="tableContent"/></f:facet>  
    </p:cellEditor>  
</p:column> 
 </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: For the last if you want ca use pattern desing